# Why am I a getting an error that react is undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and I'm importing using esmodules but I keep getting an error telling react is undefined. I'm running it through babel and then bundling it with webpack. I've looked at some of the other related questions but none seem to be helping with my problem. Why is it comming up undefined and how can I fix it?

**Error:**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:formatted:76)
    at n (bundle.js:formatted:11)
    at bundle.js:formatted:71
    at bundle.js:formatted:72
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "reactTestProject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Brandon Lind",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.2.5",
    "react": "^16.8.4"
  }
}
```

**files:**

filename: app.js

```
 import Square from "./SquareDiv.js";

let main= document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0];
console.log("wtf")

main.appendChild(<Square/>);
```

filename: SquareDiv.js

```
import React from "react";

class Square extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            isOn: true
        }
    }

    getIsOn(){
        let currentState= this.state.isOn;
        let pastState= state;
        if(currentState===false){
           currentState===true; 
        }
        else {
            currentState ===false;
        }

        return pastState;
    }

    render(){
        <div onClick={getIsOn} class="square">this.state.isOn</div>
    }
}

export {Square};
```

**babel.config.js:**

```
const presets=[
    [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
            targets:{
                esmodules: true,
                edge: 10,
                chrome: 30,
                safari: 30,
                firefox: 30,
                opera: 30
            }
        }
    ],
    [
        "@babel/preset-react",
        {
                pragma: "pragma",
                pragmaFrag: "pragmaFrag",
                throwIfNamespace: false
        }
    ]
];


module.exports={
    presets
};
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```
module.exports={
    entry: "./src/app.js",
    output:{
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module:{
        rules:[
            {  test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|browsers_components)/,
                use:{
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                            presets: ["@babel/preset-env","@babel/preset-react"]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Why 2 different import methods for react in your component files. Should just be `import React from "react";` for all files

Comment: Could you please share folder structure of the project? Or you have created project using react-create-app? Or cloned from git repository?

Comment: yeah here you go, thanks  https://github.com/BrandonLind10/reactTest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use this syntax `import React from "./node_modules/react";`.

It will work only for files that are created in the root directory, and your components are likely in `src/`.

Webpack will resolve everything for you, so you can just use `import React from 'react';` everywhere.

Also replace this string: `export {Square};` with `export default Square`

And you can omit `.js` extension when import, so you can write it this way: `import Square from "./SquareDiv";`

If you don't want to use default export, you should use `import {Square} from "./SquareDiv"`

You can read the differences between default and regular exports [here](https://hackernoon.com/import-export-default-require-commandjs-javascript-nodejs-es6-vs-cheatsheet-different-tutorial-example-5a321738b50f?gi=4bd987b2affd)

You have a lot of problems in your code snippet. I mentioned some of them in my answer. There are more of them:

- Don't use `class` keyword in JSX, it should be `className`
- Use curly braces to render JS values like `this.state.isOn`
- When you use handlers, don't use it like `onClick={getIsOn}`, use `onClick={() => getIsOn()}` and etc.

I suggest you to go through [React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html) which will save your time a lot!

Comment: oh thanks for that, I just fixed that. I was expirementing with different things trying to get it to work, including that. I reverted it back to just "react", it still doesnt work.

Comment: @brandon same error or another one? Also I am updated the answer with another little detail.

Comment: @brandon from the snippets you've shown to us it's impossible, should be another error or React error in some other component.

Comment: I tried the default Square syntax, it has the same error

Comment: In my root folder I only have babel.config.js, webpack.config.js, dist, index.html, node_modules, package.json, package-lock.json and src [app.js, SquareDiv.js]

Answer (score 1):

App.js needs to import react. Every file that has JSX in it has to import react.

This particular error is happening because the JSX for Square in app.js is getting transpiled into a React method call, and since you haven’t imported React in app.js, React is not defined.

UPDATE

Also, this will fix a couple other errors...

Change `<div onClick={getIsOn} class="square">this.state.isOn</div>` to:

`return <div onClick={this.getIsOn} className="square">{this.state.isOn}</div>`

Comment: thanks for the response, I tried that its not working

Comment: if you want to mess with it, I just added a git hub repo in the comments above. In the repo I have react imported in both files and the files are in the src folder.

Comment: I updated my answer to help with this but there are a lot of issues. You might want to run create-react-app and start with a functional project, then rebuild your content using the working framework and patterns.

Comment: ok thanks yeah I'm learning react so errors with it aren't super apparent to me yet. I figured it all out and have it running, thanks for all the help!